# android admob adeed of the screen but hides other buttons inside a ScrollView

Tags: android

I am trying to add admob at the bottom of my screen.It showing the ad but it showing at bottom of the all buttons and also it hides the logout button.I also seen other questions of this site but it does not solve my problem.can some body help me what mistake I do or what I have to do to fix it.

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
     ...
     //I just delete other buttons
     //but search also here
    ....

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/but_logout"
        style="@style/login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/but_search"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:onClick="click_but_logout"
        android:text="@string/label_logout" />
    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/ad_unit_id"/>     

</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Do you want the adview to be static on the bottom page, regardless the scrollview condition?

Comment: I want the ad at bottom of the screen.Not at the end of logout button.I added the ScrollView to see all the buttons because there are lots of button list before logout button.If i remove the the Scrollview I can see only few buttons and cannot Scrol bellow to see others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"  >
 <ScrollView
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_above="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
     ...
     //I just delete other buttons
     //but search also here
    ....

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/but_logout"
        style="@style/login"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/but_search"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:onClick="click_but_logout"
        android:text="@string/label_logout" />


</RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>    
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/ad_unit_id"/> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks It solved my problem.I just fixed one line android:above="@+id/adView" it should be android:layout_above="@+id/adView"